# ./gradlew fails with NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, macos, ssl, gradle

This is an error with running ./gradlew for the first time ever after cloning an existing codebase onto an OSX box with a lot going on.

The wrapper in question gives the following output (on another system)

```
 ./gradlew -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.12
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-03-14 08:32:03 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     b29fbb64ad6b068cb3f05f7e40dc670472129bc0

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_92 (Oracle Corporation 25.92-b14)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.10.5 x86_64
```

And the exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
  at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:198)
  at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:205)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.createSocket(HttpsClient.java:409)
  at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:162)
```

The failing OSX box is in a corporate network but not behind a proxy. It is running El Capitan 10.11.5 beta (15F31a) and has java version 1.7.0_79 and 1.8.0_45 (fails with both)

```
Java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Do I need to upgrade java, install a new cert somewhere on the system, patch gradlew...? I'm not sure where to start. The internet does not currently contain advice for this problem that doesn't lead me to dead links.

The file at

> $JAVS_HOME/jre/lib/security

is from 2014 on the broken system and last month on a non-broken system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same problem. Not sure if it's the same root cause, but seems to be related to the Java runtime version.

```
% java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

Updated to 1.8.0_66: Problem solved.

Comment: I found gradle was running as some kind of Ubuntu "snap" program, using its own version of Java that was not the same as $JAVA_HOME. Forcing it by setting `org.gradle.java.home=/path/to/java/home` in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` got the key store all sorted out